# Triggering an event by value change (

Tags: c#, events

I'm a beginner in programming and at the moment I'm looking at events. Now the reason I need an event to work is for the following situation: I run a program which gets an int, if that int changes I want to print out said int to the console.

Pretty basic and I've been looking at stackoverflow examples and looking at youtube tutorials but just can't wrap my head around events because a lot of them use complex examples. I've also looked at the ValueChanged event but I think my issue is understanding the basic event structure (or better the lack of..)

please find below the premise of the setup.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int **Number**;
            
    code that results in getting the number from somewhere and assigning it to Number ;
}
```

If I understand correctly, to be able to call the event you need a delegate, so:

1] declare the event, but I don't really get where in the code I need to do this

`public event EventHandler ValueChanged;`

2] add a new reference to that delegate (again, don't know where I would do this)

3] add a method to execute whenever the event is raised (now I'm absolutely lost, but in essence here's where I'd make a method to print out the changed value, e.g.:

```
{ 
    int NewValue;
    Console.WriteLine(NewValue); 
}
```

4] add a subscriber to the event to be able to trigger it?

My appologies if I'm saying things that don't make sense, but as mentioned I'm an absolute beginner (perhaps biting of more than I can chew, but I believe that's where you grow..)

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. please have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1 there is a good self explaining example

Comment: Yeah I've seen this but unfortunately the example complicates things more tbh. It would help me more if I know how to setup the basic event so I can work from there.